# Delete a table row jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

I have the  following script :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
      var rowCount = 1;
      $(".add_more_rows").click(function() {
          rowCount++;
          var recRow = '<p id="rowCount' + rowCount + '"><table><tr><td><label>Key Population Type :</label><?php
          $query = "SELECT * FROM `kp_types` ORDER BY Name ASC";
          if ($result = mysqli_query($link, $query)) { ?> \n\ < select class = "kp_types fieldstyle_with_label"
              required = ""
              name = "kp_typess[]"
              id = "kp_types" > \n\ <? php
              while ($idresult = mysqli_fetch_row($result)) {
                  $kp_type_id = $idresult[0];
                  $kp_type_name = $idresult[1]; ?> \n\ < option id = "partner_id"
                  value = "<?php echo $kp_type_id; ?>" > <? php echo $kp_type_name.
                  '&nbsp;'; ?> < /option>\n\<?php } ?> \n\ < /select>\n\<?php } ?> < /td>\n\ < td > < input name = "kp_targetss[]"
                  type = "text"
                  maxlength = "120"
                  style = "margin: 4px 5px 0 5px;" / > < /td>\n\\
                  n\
                      < td > < span id = "remove_row' + rowCount + '"
                  onClick = "javascript:fnRemove(this);"
                  class = "remove_row' + rowCount + '"
                  style = "font:normal 12px agency, arial; color:blue; text-decoration:underline; cursor:pointer;" > Delete Entry < /span> </td > < /tr> </table > < /p>';


                  $('.remove_row' + rowCount + '').click(function() {
                      alert('.remove_row' + rowCount + '');
                      $('#rowCount' + rowCount).remove();
                      alert('#rowCount' + rowCount);
                  });
                  $('#addedRows').append(recRow);
              });
      });

      function fnRemove(t) {
          $(t).parent('p').remove();
      }
</script>
```

I have tried deleting the  entry using the  function fnRemove(t) which is a table data in the table but it fails but when I do it while I remove the table elements and remain only with the tr and td , it deletes an entry well. How can I solve this error inside the  table element ?

Comment: can you be bit clear about your problem?

Comment: Why is this not marked as PHP?

Comment: @EdHeal it is tagged as php

Comment: Put the styling into another file. Makes the PHP easier to read and also in future to change styling.

Comment: @EdHeal, so I'm not the only one that missed the `<?php` at the end of the line and got confused about jquery's $s and php $s. Separating templating from business logic brings down the number of contextswitches my poor brain has to make. It doesn't *have* to be in a different file. Just first preparing the data in php and *then* using it in the javascript, will already be clearer.

Comment: Did you want to remove the `P` which has the table? If so, then try `$(t).parents('p').remove()` provided there is no other `P` inside the table other than the immediate parent of the table.

Comment: This question is so unclear and doesn't even make sense in some parts.  wtf is a table data.  Why are you guys even bothering trying to help this guy who can't even spend 5 minutes writing a decent question.  Not to mention his code is horrid.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask I swear I should put that link on a macro.

Answer (score 0):

in function `fnRemove` your `parent('p')` is mistake 
and correct is `parents('p')`

try this,it worked for me

```
function fnRemove(t) { 
   $(t).parents('p').remove();
}
```